# what is the recommended way of passing environment variables to a docker service

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I am using compose version 3 to start multiple services. Each service has a bunch of environment variables that need to be passed to the containers. What is the recommended way to do it?

Comment: this might help: https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/

Comment: yeah, any recommendations on using [link](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#envfile) ? over environment variables inside compose?

Comment: Whatever's easiest / more appropriate for your use case. There is no 'better' way. Sometimes I generate an env file, rather than mess with the compose file, sometimes it's just a couple and I wanna keep everything together to put it in the compose file. *shrugs*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Environment directive should be used when either there is only one service or multiple services with different environment variables. If there are multiple services using common variables, then env_file should is a much cleaner approach.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7.15
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_USER=user
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=db
    command: mysqld --lower_case_table_names=1
```

Comment: This is useful but it does not answer my question about the recommended way for environment variables? should I use the environment directive in yaml or use env_file?